# Вордпресс - список рубрик в админке

Tags: wordpress

В админке ВП при создании записи выводит выбор рубрики (справа), и там присутствуют как рубрики стандартных записей, так и рубрики произвольных типов постов. Можно как то сделать, чтобы там выводился только список рубрик стандартных записей, а в идеале, чтобы в каждом типе постов выводились только рубрики определенного типа постов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете получить список терминов с помощью функции `get_terms` https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_terms. Проверять текущий post_type и изменять выборку `get_terms`. Если вы говорите, что выводить "справа" то скорее всего имеется ввиду sidebar, тогда вам весь код нужно будет обернуть в виджет и использовать его. Подробнее: https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API